# How to use custom measure metrics in glmnet [R]?

Tags: r, cross-validation

Hi I'm doing some logistic regression, currently using `glmnet` package in R.

`glmnet` provides a few measure metrics for cross validation. For classification, we can use type.measure = 'auc' (area under ROC curve) or type.measure = 'class' (misclassification rate).

I'm working with some insurance data with a low rate of positive examples (y = 0 for 95% data, and = 1 for 5% of them. OR 95% people did't buy insurance).

```
library(ISLR)
data(Caravan)
y = dta$Purchase
x = as.matrix( dta[ , -which(colnames(dta)=='Purchase') ] )
```

And I want to predict who are likely to buy insurance.

I think I need to use F1 score or some custom metrics. For example, if I can make 200 by selling an insurance, and the cost to contact one person is 20, then I want to maximize

metric = 200 * N(true positive) - 20 * N(predicted positive)

Is there a way I can do this with glmnet or something else more suitable? Or is `AUC` a similar metric as F1 score? Any help or discussion's appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add a new objective function to the core glmnet routine, or add a new objective to a cross validation loop to choose $\lambda$?  I believe it is the second, but want to clarify.

Comment: Hi @MatthewDrury thanks for reply. What I'm thinking is using the core `glmnet`, and modify the `cv.glmnet` so that it calculates user defined metric. I was also trying to ask are there other ways? Does `AUC` work for imbalanced data? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [The caret Package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html/%22The%20caret%20Package%22).  This package uses, among many other 100's of models, the `glmnet` model.  However, caret has it's own cross validation function and allows you to specify a custom evaluation function.  Within the `trainControl` function, you should include `summaryFunction=your_custom_cv_func` where `your_custom_cv_func` takes the same form as the built-in cv functions.  See this SO answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16866460/1569064